# Replacing ' symbol from a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My data is currently in this format

'54-0000-1747'

I am trying to run the following query

```
SELECT REPLACE([CitationNumber],''','') AS [CitationNumber]  FROM TexasHarrisCountyJPPublicRecords
```

This query currently does not work because the single quote symbol is trying to convert the rest of the query into a string. All the entries in my column have a single quote at the start and at the end of the string and they are all string values, if they have no value they have '' in the cell.

Is there a syntax that will allow me to search for all single quotes in my column and replace them them with an empty string?

Comment: use `REPLACE([CitationNumber],'''','')`

Comment: Try `SELECT REPLACE([CitationNumber],'''','') AS [CitationNumber]  FROM TexasHarrisCountyJPPublicRecords`

Comment: Ask @vkp and I both said, in SQL `''` escapes a single quote.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to include the answer; that's what the Answers section is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If using SQL Server, use the Ascii code 39 representation to find the single quote.  Not as messy in my opinion:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CitationNumber, CHAR(39), '')
```

Comment: Thank you kind Sir this is EXACTLY what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little confused.  Your query is not syntactically correct.  And it mentions replacing single quotes but they are not part of the query.

To remove single quotes, you can do:

```
select replace(CitationNumber, '''', '') as CitationNumber
```

Note:  The first string is four single quotes.  The second consists of two.

Comment: Thank you for bringing this to my attention

Answer (score 0):

You need one more single quote; use this instead:

```
SELECT REPLACE([CitationNumber],'''','') 
AS [CitationNumber]  
FROM TexasHarrisCountyJPPublicRecords
```